# Get "Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/dir/' when trying to generate ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet) on how to install a generator for ASP.Net applications using yeoman. But when I run `yo aspnet` and try to generate a Web Application, I get the following error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/path/to/project/ProjectName'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:799:18)
at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
at write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/commit.js:13:12)
at DestroyableTransform._transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/commit.js:42:7)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
at doWrite (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
at writeOrBuffer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I didn't have write access to the folder I was trying to generate the app in, despite owning it. A simple `chmod` fixed it.